# How to run a wine application through terminal in a headless vps with vncserver?

Tags: server, wine, display, vnc

I have a vps with no display connected to it, but I can launch GUI apps with the vnc server. What I want to do is run these wine apps through the terminal like `wine /dir/to/application.exe` but I'm getting the following error:

```
0027:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl returning zero-filled buffer for IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
0027:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
0027:fixme:mountmgr:query_property Faking StorageDeviceProperty data
0027:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d0c10 (device=2d access=0 func=304 method=0)
0027:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl returning zero-filled buffer for IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
0027:fixme:mountmgr:query_property Faking StorageDeviceProperty data
0027:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
0027:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d0c10 (device=2d access=0 func=304 method=0)
0009:fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 0x32f0dc, 0x32f0ec 0x32f0e0
0009:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x32f0dc 0x32f0ec 0x32f0e0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0009:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0009:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod FFFFFFFA, 0032FEAC
```

I know the solution to this is to set `DISPLAY=:0` but it's not working maybe because it doesn't really have display?

I tried `xranr --listmonitors` it's telling me `Can't open display`

How can I do this so that it runs the wine app on my VNC display? Thanks!